Problemas de conexion en cluster de aws redis con django
No se el porque cuesta mucho conectar celery con los clusters de redis en aws
Este es mi celery_app.py
import os
from celery import Celery
from rediscluster import RedisCluster

app = Celery('your_app')

app.conf.update(
    broker_url='redis://xxxxxx.xxxx.xxxx.memorydb.region.amazonaws.com:6379/0',
    result_backend='redis://xxxxxx.xxxx.xxxx.memorydb.region.amazonaws.com:6379/0',
    broker_transport_options={
        'cluster': True,  # Enable cluster mode
    },
    broker_connection_retry_on_startup=True,

)

# Custom method to create RedisCluster instance
def get_redis_cluster():
    startup_nodes = [
        {"host": "xxxxxx.xxxx.xxxx.memorydb.region.amazonaws.com", "port": 6379},
        # Add other startup nodes if applicable
    ]
    return RedisCluster(startup_nodes=startup_nodes, decode_responses=True)

# Use this function where RedisCluster is needed directly
redis_cluster_instance = get_redis_cluster()
# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()

y este es mi local.py
CACHES = {
  'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',

    "LOCATION": [
            "redis://xxxxxx.xxxx.xxxx.memorydb.region.amazonaws.com:6379/0",
            "redis://xxxxxx.xxxx.xxxx.memorydb.region.amazonaws.com:6379/1",
    ],
    'OPTIONS': {
      'REDIS_CLIENT_CLASS': 'rediscluster.RedisCluster',
      'CONNECTION_POOL_CLASS': 'rediscluster.connection.ClusterConnectionPool',
      'CONNECTION_POOL_KWARGS': {
        'skip_full_coverage_check': True # AWS ElasticCache has disabled CONFIG commands
      }
    }
  }
}

al levantar con el comando docker compose -f docker-compose.local.yml up celerybeat celeryworker
Me genera el siguiente error:
sport_local_celeryworker  |     raise RedisClusterException("ERROR sending 'config get cluster-require-full-coverage' command to redis server: {0}".format(node))
sport_local_celerybeat    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rediscluster/nodemanager.py", line 375, in node_require_full_coverage
sport_local_celeryworker  | rediscluster.exceptions.RedisClusterException: ERROR sending 'config get cluster-require-full-coverage' command to redis server: {'host': '10.20.137.97', 'port': 6379, 'name': '10.20.137.97:6379', 'server_type': 'master'}
sport_local_celerybeat    |     raise RedisClusterException("ERROR sending 'config get cluster-require-full-coverage' command to redis server: {0}".format(node))
sport_local_celeryworker  |
sport_local_celerybeat    | rediscluster.exceptions.RedisClusterException: ERROR sending 'config get cluster-require-full-coverage' command to redis server: {'host': '10.20.137.97', 'port': 6379, 'name': '10.20.137.97:6379', 'server_type': 'master'}

Alguna solución a este problema, perdonen que las molestias, agradecido con la ayuda que puedan brindarme
